# Want to implement ng-bootstrap tool-tip or any other tool-tip on hovering over the angular-slickgrid cell data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, slickgrid, angular-slickgrid

I want to implement ng-bootstrap tool-tip(or any other tool-tip if that works) which will be shown when user hover over the data present inside slickgrid cells.
I am also attaching a snapshot of expected functionality below. I need to show similar kind of black tool-tip with some information when user hovers over the slick-grid data.[image]

This is not possible through formatters and when I am rendering an angular component inside grid cells so that I could easily use ngb-tooltip there, then the tooltip is getting cropped to the size of grid-cell's dimensions. Part outside the area of grid-cell isn't visible. Even high z-index not working for it to be visible.

Help me out in this by suggesting some methods to implement this.

Comment: on the `ngb-tooltip` add attribute `container="body"`

Comment: there is a tooltips example page: http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-autotooltips.html

Comment: these kind of questions were answered quite some time ago, this SO [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778258/cell-tooltip-in-slickgrid) it will and you will need to use the Autotooltip plugin as mentioned by Ben, in Angular-Slickgrid you can enable it via `enableAutoTooltip: true` flag